# Run Geoprocessing Tool w/ Shortcut Key

Tags: arcgis-pro, shortcuts

I can finish drawing a feature with a double click or F2, but I cannot run a geoprocessing tool with the same ease.

I tried looking to Esri for guidance but the page itself only makes a reference to a "Mouse Click" to run a tool, but no shortcut key...

[image]

> Run a geoprocessing tool by clicking the Run button at the bottom
>   of the Geoprocessing pane.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/run-geoprocessing-tools.htm

Using ArcGIS Pro, how might I make a custom key, if a shortcut key for this does not already exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** This functionality has been implemented as of Pro 2.5. Per the answer from Matt, use `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`

**Original Answer (April 2019 - Pro 2.4 and older)**
There is no short cut key to quickly run/launch a geoprocessing tool. Your only option would be keyboard navigation using `tab` and then `enter` once "Run" is in focus.

You cannot add the "Run" button to the ribbon menu as an item (it does not exist as an option to put in there from the **Customize the Ribbon** in the options). I bring this up as generally any item you can put into the ribbon can be hot-keyed. (you may need to use an add-in to do this...read on)

Your only option, and I'm *very* skeptical it'd work, would be to create an Add-in that calls the tools run button. I know you can [hot-key items you create using add-ins](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProSnippets-Framework#application-accelerators-shortcut-keys), but I doubt the ability to grab the **run** button and fire it (based on no Run button in the Customize option). I say this as the Run button is not a global button, it lives on the geoprocessing pane as part of the tool dialog.

If this functionality is important to you, I'd suggest adding an idea on ideas.arcgis.com

This answer is based on my direct experience working on the Geoprocessing Team at Esri, not on any documentation. (Mind you, ArcGIS Pro is evolving rapidly, so I'd be happy to be proved wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Conveniently this keyboard shortcut is now packaged with ArcGIS Pro [as of version 2.5](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/shortcut-to-run-a-geoprocessing-tool/td-p/578559#:%7E:text=The%20geoprocessing%20team%20is%20providing,in%20the%20Pro%202.5%20release.). The shortcut is `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. I just tested it and it works perfectly.